Why is it not possible to use spacebars to insert a style for an HTML element?
I'm really struggling with the following:
<td class="left {{tableStyle}}" {{background}} >{{value}}</td>

And my JS code:
{'background':'style="background-color:red;"'}


This results into Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'style="background-color:red;"' is not a valid attribute name.
I tried insert only values (e.g. style={{data}}) etc. but this is not even possible to run.

You have a typo, change backgriund to background.

@Amirreza Yes, I wrote it on my phone. The actual code has no typos.

Here is the corrected code:
HTML: <td class="left {{style}}" style="{{background}}">{{value}}</td>
JS: {style: 'ClassName', background: 'background-color:red;', value: 'Content'}
The anatomy of your code is wrong, it goes this way in reality: for each attribute you use in your HTML you should provide an attribute-value pair this way:
HTML: {{Attribute}}, JS: {Attribute: 'Value'}
In your original code, if overlooking the typos, there are no values for style and value parameters.
